# Using Postcodes.IO array for data callback

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the [postcodes.io](http://postcodes.io) website to bulk check postcodes using the below code and while print_r works fine when i try to use foreach i get a error 500 message.

Anyone know where i'm going wrong:

```
require 'Postcodes-IO-PHP.php';
$postcode = new Postcode();
$lookup = $postcode->bulkLookup(array("UB4 9LL","TW5 0LY","W6 8LL"));
//print_r($lookup); // Works fine

foreach($lookup as $item):
      echo '<span>'.$item['postcode'].'</span>';
      echo '<span>'.$item['parliamentary_constituency'].'</span>';
      echo '<span>'.$item['admin_district'].';</span>';
endforeach;
```

I've also included the bulkLookup class from the Postcodes-IO-PHP.php file:

```
public function bulkLookup($postcodes){
            $data_string = json_encode(array('postcodes' => $postcodes));

            $ch = curl_init('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
            );

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $result = json_decode($result);

            return $result->result;

        }
```

**EDIT: Example Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [query] => TW5 0LY
            [result] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [postcode] => TW5 0LY
                    [quality] => 1
                    [eastings] => 513138
                    [northings] => 177155
                    [country] => England
                    [nhs_ha] => London
                    [longitude] => -0.37209917055311
                    [latitude] => 51.482044755215
                    [parliamentary_constituency] => Feltham and Heston
                    [european_electoral_region] => London
                    [primary_care_trust] => Hounslow
                    [region] => London
                    [lsoa] => Hounslow 011D
                    [msoa] => Hounslow 011
                    [incode] => 0LY
                    [outcode] => TW5
                    [admin_district] => Hounslow
                    [parish] => Hounslow, unparished area
                    [admin_county] => 
                    [admin_ward] => Heston East
                    [ccg] => NHS Hounslow
                    [nuts] => Hounslow and Richmond upon Thames
                    [codes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [admin_district] => E09000018
                            [admin_county] => E99999999
                            [admin_ward] => E05000356
                            [parish] => E43000208
                            [ccg] => E38000084
                            [nuts] => UKI75
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [query] => UB4 9LL
            [result] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [postcode] => UB4 9LL
                    [quality] => 1
                    [eastings] => 511267
                    [northings] => 182446
                    [country] => England
                    [nhs_ha] => London
                    [longitude] => -0.3973643481139
                    [latitude] => 51.529970749762
                    [parliamentary_constituency] => Hayes and Harlington
                    [european_electoral_region] => London
                    [primary_care_trust] => Hillingdon
                    [region] => London
                    [lsoa] => Hillingdon 020D
                    [msoa] => Hillingdon 020
                    [incode] => 9LL
                    [outcode] => UB4
                    [admin_district] => Hillingdon
                    [parish] => Hillingdon, unparished area
                    [admin_county] => 
                    [admin_ward] => Yeading
                    [ccg] => NHS Hillingdon
                    [nuts] => Harrow and Hillingdon
                    [codes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [admin_district] => E09000017
                            [admin_county] => E99999999
                            [admin_ward] => E05000344
                            [parish] => E43000207
                            [ccg] => E38000082
                            [nuts] => UKI74
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [query] => W6 8LL
            [result] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [postcode] => W6 8LL
                    [quality] => 1
                    [eastings] => 523864
                    [northings] => 177965
                    [country] => England
                    [nhs_ha] => London
                    [longitude] => -0.21742782750815
                    [latitude] => 51.487079216243
                    [parliamentary_constituency] => Hammersmith
                    [european_electoral_region] => London
                    [primary_care_trust] => Hammersmith and Fulham
                    [region] => London
                    [lsoa] => Hammersmith and Fulham 014A
                    [msoa] => Hammersmith and Fulham 014
                    [incode] => 8LL
                    [outcode] => W6
                    [admin_district] => Hammersmith and Fulham
                    [parish] => Hammersmith and Fulham, unparished area
                    [admin_county] => 
                    [admin_ward] => Fulham Reach
                    [ccg] => NHS Hammersmith and Fulham
                    [nuts] => Kensington & Chelsea and Hammersmith & Fulham
                    [codes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [admin_district] => E09000013
                            [admin_county] => E99999999
                            [admin_ward] => E05000255
                            [parish] => E43000203
                            [ccg] => E38000070
                            [nuts] => UKI33
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of both the error and the value of `print_r($lookup)`?

Comment: The error is just a standard Error 500 Chrome: domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: I think you may need to do ``foreach($lookup->result as $item):`` and use ``$item->postcode`` instead of ``$item['postcode']`` etc, as ``json_decode`` returns objects, not arrays by default.

Comment: You need to use `json_decode($result, true)` if you want it to return an associative array.

Comment: Does "bulk" lookup work for a single postcode?

Comment: Yes bulk works for a single lookup

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after reading about `StdClass` it made a lot more sense. I've included a full working example for anyone else who may come acorss the same issue.

This method uses a `textarea` input to post the postcodes with each postcode being on a new line:

```
// Required postcode.io Class
require 'Postcodes-IO-PHP.php';

// Prepares the postcode array by removing new lines
$query = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST["postcodes"])); 

// Runs the postcode lookup and returns return
$postcode = new Postcode();
$lookup = $postcode->bulkLookup($query);

// Output results
foreach($lookup as $item):
    echo "Postcode: ".$item->query."<br>";
    echo "District: ".$item->result->admin_district."<br>";
    echo "Constituency: ".$item->result->parliamentary_constituency."<br>";
eachforeach
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea name="postcodes"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Search Postcodes">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This would output something similar for each postcode submitted:

```
Postcode: SW1A 1AA
District: Westminster
Constituency: Cities of London and Westminster
```